# How to test Klein server in python

Tags: python, testing, python-unittest, klein-mvc

I have made an *async* `http api` in `Python` using `Klein`. I would like to test my requests using something like `Unittest` or similar.

I have found [this](https://seminar.io/2013/09/27/testing-your-rest-client-in-python/) but I'm not sure I'll be able to implement it remotely the same way.

Is there a correct and direct approach to do something similar to what was done in the example I've found?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [responses](https://pypi.org/project/responses/0.5.1/) or [requests-mock](https://pypi.org/project/requests-mock/) python libraries.
They both provide great features for testing HTTP requests.